# idiomatic way of drawing a triangle in d3

Tags: d3.js

I have the following code that draws a triangle in d3:

```
var trianglePoints = xScale(3) + ' ' + yScale(18) + ', ' + xScale(1) + ' ' + yScale(0) + ', ' + xScale(12) + ' ' + yScale(3) + ' ' + xScale(12) + ', ' + yScale(3) + ' ' + xScale(3) + ' ' + yScale(18);

console.log(trianglePoints);

svg.append('polyline')
    .attr('points', trianglePoints)
    .style('stroke', 'blue');
```

Here is a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/coyepa/1/edit?js,output) which shows it in action.

I am curious to know if this is the best way of doing in this d3 or is there a better way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mike Bostock, the creator of D3, thinks that what you're doing is the best method:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/d3-js/kHONjIWjAA0

> Yep, I'd probably use a path element with a custom "d" attribute here.
>
> Another option for drawing triangles, but more intended for
>   scatterplots, is to use d3.svg.symbol. See the documentation here:
>
> https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#wiki-symbol

Answer (score 12):

Another example using v4 of [shape symbols](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#symbols):

```
var color = "green";
var triangleSize = 25;
var verticalTransform = midHeight + Math.sqrt(triangleSize);

var triangle = d3.symbol()
            .type(d3.symbolTriangle)
            .size(triangleSize)
;

svg.append("path")
            .attr("d", triangle)
            .attr("stroke", color)
            .attr("fill", color)
            .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + xScale(currentPrice) + "," + yScale(verticalTransform) + ")"; });
    ;
```

Some notes:

- the size of the shape seems to be an area
- the shape is centered at [0, 0]

The above example is trying to translate the top point of the equilateral triangle rather than the center, hence the extra amount to the "y" portion of the transfrom.

Answer (score 7):

There is an [inbuilt convenience function](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#symbol_type) for drawing various symbols for use in Scatterplots, as stated by Kyle R. If you are only interested in drawing an equilateral triangle, then this could be used.

The function can used like so:

```
svg.append("path")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.x) + "," + y(d.y) + ")"; })
    .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol().type("triangle-up"));
```

You can also set the size of the symbol: by appending the function call `size(100)`.

That said, if you want to draw a different form of triangle you can either:

1. draw a `path` element and use the `d` attribute. [Path element explained](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_path.asp).
2. draw a `polygon` or `polyline` with a `points` attribute (as you have done in your example).

To use to `d` attribute. I've forked your [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/tekekiyuwo/1/edit?js,output) to demo it. The key snippet is as follows:

```
svg.append('path')
    .attr('d', function(d) { 
      var x = xScale(3), y = yScale(18);
      return 'M ' + x +' '+ y + ' l ' + xScale(10) + ' ' + yScale(10) + ' l ' + -xScale(10) + ' ' + yScale(20) + ' z';
    })
    .style('stroke', 'blue');
```